# How do I count multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

How do I count rows that have identical values in columns A,B,C,D ?

The column 'ID' will be ignored.

For this case, the count result is 2.

Comment: you need it in Linq query for Linq2Sql or just in SQL. I can't understand how 'C#' tag related to your question.

Comment: @Samich, I am using c# to do this sql command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), A, B, C, D
 FROM dbo.YourTable
 GROUP BY A, B, C, D
 -- optional - if you want to skip all the rows that occur only once
 -- HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Basically, you just group your data by the columns of interest, and let SQL count the rows that match each set of column values.