# How to generate a table with one row for each count of distinct possibilities from one column, including null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After another edit, here is a new title and a new scope, with the old one preserved.

Take this sample data...

```
    ('1', 'male'),
    ('2', 'female'),
    ('3', 'other'),
    ('4', 'male'),
    ('5', 'female'),
    ('6', 'male'),
    ('7', null);
```

And turn it into this...

```
gender   cnt
female   2
male     3
null     1
other    1
```

Here is pre-edit...

I generate a table using `PIVOT` containing dynamically generated column names based upon the distinct row values.

Here's some sample data...

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([id] varchar(5), [gender] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #tmp
    ([id], [gender])
VALUES
    ('1', 'male'),
    ('2', 'female'),
    ('3', 'other'),
    ('4', 'male'),
    ('5', 'female'),
    ('6', 'male'),
    ('7', null);
```

Here's the code to produce the result table (using some code from [Convert row value in to column in SQL server (PIVOT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916470/convert-row-value-in-to-column-in-sql-server-pivot) and [How do I count multiple columns in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346127/how-do-i-count-multiple-columns-in-sql-server) )

```
---Using Dynamic Pivot
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(gender) 
    from #tmp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT count(*) as cnt,' + @cols + ' 
         from 
         (
            Select id, gender
            from #tmp
         ) dta
         pivot 
         (
            MAX(gender)
            for gender in (' + @cols + ')
         ) pvt 
         group by ' + @cols

 execute(@query);
```

Which produces the following...

```
cnt female  male    other
1   NULL    NULL    NULL
1   NULL    NULL    other
3   NULL    male    NULL
2   female  NULL    NULL
```

From that, I want to (dynamically - can't explicitly specify the column names 'null', 'other', 'female', 'male', etc.) produce the following...

```
gender   cnt
null     1
other    2
male     3
female   2
```

Besides producing the final result, the tricky part for me has been getting the 'null' row because there is no corresponding result column named 'null'. I have attempted this from the perspective of using `UNPIVOT` or `PIVOT` again. So the question is, how can I produce this final result table from the results of my pivot and count? Is there a simpler, more efficient method that does it all?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand exactly what is the problem... Why not use Count and group? No need really to pivot/unpivot (I think)

```
select gender, count(*) as cnt from #tmp group by gender
```

hope it helps a bit?

Comment: thank you. I feel so stupid. I'm voting to delete. That was pretty bad. Talk about over thinking something?

Comment: No worries... not the first time, not the last